# How to setup a swagger API login with authorize button in asp.net web api?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, access-token, swagger-ui

I have an asp.net web api project integrated with swagger ui. I am new in swagger.I installed all required OWIN packages for authentication.It works fine with postman but when i give authorize attribute in any controller it's not working in swagger.

How can i make a login panel for authentication in swagger and how to add the bearer+access_token automatically with every request in swagger after successful login?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did in a .net core project (2.2). This might help you in setting up authentication with swagger. I'm using swashbackle and Microsoft.OpenApi:

**1-Add authentication Support:**

```
services.AddAuthentication("ApiKey").AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, ApiKeyAuth>("ApiKey", null);
```

**2-Add this in the AddSwaggerGen in the ConfigureServices method:**

```
            setup.AddSecurityDefinition("ApiKey", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Name = "ApiKey",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Please enter the API Key provided to you"
            });

            setup.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "ApiKey" }
                    }, new List<string>() }
            });
```

**3-Create your authentication handler:**

```
public class ApiKeyAuth : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{

    public ApiKeyAuth(
         IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
         ILoggerFactory logger,
         UrlEncoder encoder,
         ISystemClock clock)
         : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }
    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {

        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("ApiKey"))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing ApiToken"));
        }
        try
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity( new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "1") },Scheme.Name);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authentication Failed"));
        }

    }
}
```

you need to implement this properly since this a testing code.

As a result, you should see a new Authorize button appearing on the UI:

[image]

The authorize dialog box should look like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: As i am using asp.net web api not asp.net core can you help me regrading that ? I already getting token by postman but i need to generate token from swagger ui by authorization and that token will automatically add with authorization header in curl of every request. Could you please guide or help me ? @Oualid KTATA

Answer (score 0):

The ApiKeyAuth class is not called.

I have added [Authorize] to the controller.

Added this code to StartUp.

services.AddAuthentication("ApiKey").AddScheme("ApiKey", null);

Comment: Hi Glenn. Are you asking a question? Or are you answering the original question? It's a bit unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in Program file to authorize button on swagger page

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>{
option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Portal API", Version = "v1" });
option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Description = "Please enter a valid token",
    Name = "Authorization",
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
    BearerFormat = "JWT",
    Scheme = "Bearer"
});
option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id="Bearer"
            }
        },
        new string[]{}
    }
});
});
```